# How can i delete message on click of bubble touch? React Native Gifted chat library

Tags: react-native, chat, react-native-gifted-chat

I have developed chat view in React Native using [gifted](https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-gifted-chat) chat lib. But i want to perform delete action on click of chat bubble.

I have try custom renderCustomView ,lightboxProps  and onLongPress  props but none of  is working.

Answer (score 8):

add onLongPress to GiftedChat component like this

```
<GiftedChat
       onLongPress={this.onLongPress}
    
       ....
       ....
/>
```

onLongPress returns `context, message`. Then you can show an ActionSheet and add your logic to delete.

```
    onLongPress(context, message) {
        console.log(context, message);
        const options = ['Delete Message', 'Cancel'];
        const cancelButtonIndex = options.length - 1;
        context.actionSheet().showActionSheetWithOptions({
            options,
            cancelButtonIndex
        }, (buttonIndex) => {
            switch (buttonIndex) {
                case 0:
                    // Your delete logic
                    break;
                case 1:
                    break;
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: can u help with the logic to delete a message? :)

Comment: let temp = messages.filter(temp => message._id !== temp._id);
            this.setState({
              messages: temp,
            });